# Can a proper noun be a predicative in imperatives?

Tags: nouns, imperatives, predicate

I live in a city called Kobe in the western part of Japan.　　Perhaps some of you might have known that it was severely hit and damaged by the Great Hanshin Earthquake some 20 years ago.　　The　City,　however,　recovered　now　and　the　City　Authority　has　been　running　a　campaign commemorating the recovery with a motto 'Be Kobe'.

I have some queries about this motto from a grammatical point of view.

1. Is the 'motto' acceptable or interpretable given a context outlined above?
2. If it is interpretable, what can it possibly mean?

Any comments are more than welcome.

Ken

Comment: Can you tell us why you suspect the motto may not be grammatically acceptable? Have you considered what all the phrase could mean, if it indeed is grammatical?

Comment: I see nothing ungrammatical, though it provides an impossible and illogical command. It is, though, idiomatic within the context of a motto, or mantra. (I have fond memories of Kobe, from when I lived there in 1973-4, especially the views of the city at night from Rokko Mountain. That was long before the earthquake.)

Comment: A quick answer to Kris.  Orders or commands have to be made under certain conditions apparently.  As WS2 says, this motto seems to be semantically odd.  Orders should be made to the hearer on the condition that they are able to be achieved or at least there is possibility that they can be achieved.  Coming back to the motto 'Be Kobe', how can you be 'Kobe' anyway?  Certainly you can try to be 'Kobe' if 'Kobe' is meant to be mean something like 'what a typical citizen of Kobe is like'

Comment: ... Soyez l'état!

Answer (score -1):

We can — and often do — say ["be yourself"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22be+yourself%22), meaning roughly "behave in accordance with your true personality/values/preferences/interests/etc., rather than pretending to have different ones in order to impress people/fit in/etc."

I take the "be Kobe" motto to be saying the same thing, but at the scale of a city rather than an individual: it sounds like it's telling the people of Kobe that they don't need to be like Tokyo or Kyoto (or whatever the obvious point of comparison might be), that the city's personality/culture is just fine the way it is, and that they should be proud of it and live Kobe-ishly. (Another way to express the same idea might be "Be yourself, Kobe!") So the motto is saying something positive; that the people of Kobe should feel proud of their city; but it's perhaps also acknowledging something a bit negative, that perhaps not all the people of Kobe currently feel proud. (Though I'm not entirely sure that the people who came up with the slogan were really intending that last part . . . with such a short slogan, it's easy to read too much into it!)

That said, I definitely agree with WS2's comment above that it is only "idiomatic within the context of a motto, or mantra". It's a bit of a strange thing to say, but slogans are *often* a bit strange. This (hopefully) makes them memorable and fun.

Comment: "Be yourself" is no problem as far as the syntax is concerned, because 'yourself' can be a nominal predicate after a copula.  As for 'Kobe' in "Be Kobe.",  is it possible for 'Kobe' can occupy a nominal predicate position after 'be' whatever it means.  I am just wondering if you can say "Be New York", intending to mean "Be a New Yorker'.  What I am asking is whether or not a place name like 'Kobe' can represent a quality of the people who live there.

Comment: @KenSugayama: I think that you downvoted my answer without reading past the first paragraph?

Answer (score -3):

It's not an English sentence and ***be*** here is not the English verb.

The [**BE KOBE monument**](https://matcha-jp.com/en/4858?page=3), installed in April 2017, is by the water at the park’s south edge. It is popular enough that there is often of those wanting to take photos here on the weekends. “BE KOBE” is a message created to mark the passage of two decades since the Great Hanshin-Awaji Earthquake. It shows Kobe residents’ pride in their city, and their passion to use all their energy to help others.
[image]

There is no one to manage the line, but people queue up naturally anyway, so get in line. Strike up a conversation with the people in front and behind you as you wait.

The monument, including the base, is 2.4 meters tall, so climbing it is very dangerous. Avoid doing this at all costs.
[image]

Comment: The only part of this answer which is relevant to English is the first sentence, and even that doesn't say what *Be* actually is.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That first sentence cannot be made without the substantiation below it, for an answer.

Comment: There is nothing which substantiates the first sentence. If there is, please make it clearer (perhaps a *because* might help). It seems to me that since it's written in Latin letters, *be* is certainly an English word, and that means it's the imperative form of the verb. Why is it not that?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Those who can benefit from the information already provided would. Even I am not satisfied with the answer, but this is not the place for a dissertation.

Comment: Actually this **is** just the place for a dissertation! Write an answer worthy of a site for English language professionals.